# Persist in SQL API in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I use the SQL API of Spark SQL (v2.4) to submit and run sql queries on EMR.

From time to time, if need be I cache temp views to speed-up my queries by running :

```
create temp view my_tab
as
select id, name, age
from emp
where age > 35;
....

CACHE TABLE my_tab;
```

However, I am wondering if there is any equivalent way to use `persist()` in the SQL API where I can persist the data temporarily by using options such as `MEMORY` or `DISK` ?

*Note: My question pertains to only the SQL API.*

Spark SQL v2.4

Thanks

Comment: No is also an answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, only in Spark version 3.x can you do such things. See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-aux-cache-cache-table.html